# Changing umask value

Tags: permissions, chmod, umask

I want to change `umask` value from 022 to 002 for a particular user `jboss`. Right now it is set as follows in /etc/profile:

```
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
umask 002
 else
umask 022
fi
```

If I change `/etc/profile` , it will impact all users but I want to change the setting for `jboss` user only. For this I can edit `.basrhrc/.bash_profile` under user's home directory . But the issue for me is that the user does not have a shell . Any way to set `umask` for users without shell .

Answer (score 3):

The `umask` is a property of a process, not a user.

It is inherited by children and preserved across execution of commands even setuid ones.

It is set with the `umask()` system call. The shell interface to that `umask()` system call is the `umask` builtin command.

There is no magical way to have the umask be changed whenever a process changes uid, but some programs that are typically used to change uids can be configured to. That's the case of those using the PAM stack on Linux at least (typically login programs), using the `pam_umask` module, or `sudo`.

But here, given that that user doesn't have a shell, I suppose it's not one that logs in, and you actually want one particular software run as that user to have that umask. Then, that should be just a matter of starting that software with:

```
(umask 002; exec that-software)
```

In a shell script.

Comment: It is a java process for me with a Web interface. When we try to upload an image using this process of creates a new directory without write permission for group owner. We want to change the umask so that every new directory is created with write permission for group.

Comment: @ZamaQues, yes, sounds like you just need to start that java command as `umask 002; java ...`